# Convert nested json to spark dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and have been trying to get the API data I called into a dataframe. When I make the API call I get a json with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- bbox: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- geometry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- alert: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cdi: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- detail: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- dmin: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- felt: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- gap: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ids: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- mag: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- magType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- mmi: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- net: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- nst: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- place: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- rms: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- sig: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- sources: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- time: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- tsunami: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- types: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- tz: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- updated: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- api: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- generated: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- status: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

I am using the following to create a dataframe

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(path)
```

and get the result of

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|                bbox|            features|            metadata|             type|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|[-92.6998333, 35....|[{{[-89.5175, 36....|{1.13.3, 24, 1647...|FeatureCollection|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

using df.show()

My ideal dataframe would be

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|  mag         |    location |    time     |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

with the data pulled from each property from the schema.

I've looked at numerous functions that people write to pull data but they all seem to be specific to the schema. I'm having a hard time converting my schema. Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Define the schema for each of features, metadata etc.
For eg.

```
meta_schema = StructType([StructField("api", StringType()), StructField("count", LongType()), StructField("generated", LongType()),StructField("status", LongType()), StructField("title", StringType()), StructField("url", StringType())])
```

Step 2: use from_json

```
df1 =df.withColumn("meta_explained", from_json("metadata", meta_schema))
```

Step 3: Extract data
Then you can extract each item from the struct easily.

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("meta_title", df1.meta_explained.title)
```

If your data has array,

```
features_schema = ArrayType(StructType(...))
```

You can use explode and then work through to obtain the "mag" property.